# change the text of buttons from database (list of string)

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm new to vb.net so I'm seeking for help,
I have method to create buttons in panel layout, and what I want is to set the TEXT for each button from database table ( but the customer TEXT ),
so how can I do it?

this is the method to generate buttons:

```
Private Sub GenerateTable(columnCount As Integer, rowCount As Integer)
    'Clear out the existing controls, we are generating a new table layout
    TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear()

    'Clear out the existing row and column styles
    TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Clear()
    TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Clear()

    'Now we will generate the table, setting up the row and column counts first
    TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = columnCount
    TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = rowCount

    For x As Integer = 0 To columnCount - 1
        'First add a column
        TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize))

        For y As Integer = 0 To rowCount - 1
            'Next, add a row.  Only do this when once, when creating the first column
            If x = 0 Then
                TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize))
            End If

            'Create the control, in this case we will add a button
            Dim cmd As New Button()
            cmd.Width = 200
            cmd.Height = 40
            Dim count As Integer = TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType(Of Button)().ToList().Count
            fill_combobox
            cmd.Name = "button_" & (count + 1)
            cmd.Text = "button_" & (count + 1)
            AddHandler cmd.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
            Panel1.Controls.Add(cmd)
            'cmd.Text = String.Format("({0}, {1})", x, y)
            'Finally, add the control to the correct location in the table
            TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(cmd, x, y)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

this is how to call all customers TEXT or id as list of strings from database :

```
Dim myList As New List(Of String)()
Private Sub fill_combobox()
    Try
        If SQL.conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            SQL.conn.Close()
        End If
        SQL.conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
        cmd.Connection = SQL.conn
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT cust_id FROM customers order by date"
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While dr.Read
            Dim esection As String = dr.Item(0)
            myList.Add(String.Format(esection))
        End While
        dr.Close()
        SQL.conn.Close()

    Catch ex As SqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "SQL Error")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "General Error")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im elaborating on Subazs' comment. It could be easier to create a collection or List(of Button) then add all of your buttons into this as you itterate them into the flowtable. You can then call back to these at a later date, they will be stored in the list until you dispose of the form. NOTE they are with the form if you code it like this.

I have altered your code slightly too, you must remember to dispose the cmd as well as closing the connection (I had an awful experience not doing this which cost me!)

```
Dim myList As New List(Of String)
Dim myButtons As List(Of Button)

Public Sub Run_Me()
    Retrieve_Customers()
    'You can change the 5 and it will change the layout panel for you... :)
    GenerateTable_and_Buttons(5)
    MsgBox("All done!")
End Sub

'Replaces your (Fill_Combo_Box) method
Private Sub Retrieve_Customers()
    Try
        myList = New List(Of String)
        If Sql.conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then Sql.conn.Close()
        Sql.conn.Open()

        'Do you want to add in the customer name instead of ID? - if so we can change here...
        Dim qry As String = "SELECT cust_id FROM customers order by date"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(qry, Sql.conn)
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read
            Dim s As String = dr.Item(0)
            myList.Add(String.Format(s))
        End While
        dr.Close()

        cmd.Dispose()
        Sql.conn.Close()

    Catch ex As SqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "SQL Error")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "General Error")
    End Try

    'Now we have built a list of the customer - myList we can go on to count these...

End Sub

Private Sub GenerateTable_and_Buttons(columnCount As Integer)
    If myList Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'Just exit if we have no customers?
    myButtons = New List(Of Button)

    'This will round UP to make sure we have enough rows - also can do something like +1 on end if want extra?
    Dim rowCount As Integer = CInt(Math.Round(Math.Ceiling(myList.Count / columnCount), 0))
    Dim tlp As TableLayoutPanel = Me.TableLayoutPanel1

    'Clear out the existing controls, we are generating a new table layout
    tlp.Controls.Clear()

    'Clear out the existing row and column styles
    tlp.ColumnStyles.Clear()
    tlp.RowStyles.Clear()

    'Now we will generate the table, setting up the row and column counts first
    tlp.ColumnCount = columnCount
    tlp.RowCount = rowCount

    Dim count As Integer = 0

    For x As Integer = 0 To columnCount - 1
        'First add a column
        tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize))

        For y As Integer = 0 To rowCount - 1
            'Next, add a row.  Only do this when once, when creating the first column
            If x = 0 Then
                tlp.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize))
            End If

            'Create the control, in this case we will add a button
            Dim cmd As New Button
            cmd.Width = 200
            cmd.Height = 40

            '<<Add the customer ID into the TAG of the control, the tag is great place to store things
            'We can then access the tag in another method, ie if we want to open it using your Button_Click
            'method. We can say :
            'Dim CustID As String = sender.Tag
            'Then we can do other things with the ID....>>

            If mylist.count > count then
            cmd.Tag = myList(count)
            cmd.Text = myList(count)
            end if

            'fill_combobox() ' I dont know why this is here?

            cmd.Name = "button_" & (count + 1)
            cmd.Text = "button_" & (count + 1)
            AddHandler cmd.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
            myButtons.Add(cmd)

            '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            Panel1.Controls.Add(cmd) '<<<<<<<<< Whats Panel1????
            '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

            'Finally, add the control to the correct location in the table
            tlp.Controls.Add(cmd, x, y)

            count += 1
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you man, I'm grateful for the answer, really thank you. I have a question, is there a way to make the buttons count as the row count in database table, what I mean that I want the button to be just X buttons, but I want each row to have 4 buttons, so if I have 8 buttons, it will show 5 buttons in the first row and show 3 buttons in the second row.
thank you again

Comment: We can make it programatic to count the customers and add however many buttons we need. However, Im struggling to picture the layout you want, is it 2x4 or (5 +3 +{2 blank}) if its fixed on one either column or row, and variable on the other then its easier.
ie we can have 4 columns, then the rows can get larger and more buttons as we have more customers, or have 4 rows, and the columns get more...?

Comment: yes exactly, I want 5 columns fixed, and the rows will be counted from a database table, so if I have 10 rows it will be 10 rows \ 5 columns so it will be 2 rows in the panel layout.
what I trying to achieve from all this is to show all customers name from the table in form, so the user can search or chose customer so when he clicks on any customer another form will shows.

Comment: Ok give me some time, think I know where we're going now, i'll put some code together..

Comment: I've updated should now be dynamic rows and columns (depending on how many customers you have..) I cant really check too much from my side, but read over few times, should be good to go. I did wonder why you were calling the 'Fill_Combo' method for every x,y itteration? I've taken it out, so if you run the "Run_Me" it will grab all the customers, then add all the buttons. 

Hope this points you in the right directio :)

Comment: unfortunately,  I get an error in 'cmd.Tag = myList(count)' and this is the error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, should be counting before to see if there is a customer or not - at present it will just fill multiple of 5 - ie if we have 12 customers (with 5 columns) it will have 15 buttons, albeit 3 wont have any customer attached Should work now

Comment: It's working now but, the cust Id not shown in the button text.

Comment: Added the line cmd.text = mylist(count) sorry!

Comment: it's work prefect now, but the column 5 not shown cust id, 
in the row number 1, all buttons showing the cust id to button 4, button 5 is without text, and the row 2 also the same( the button text work to button 4 then starts at the next row)